# Xcode 10 can't show subclass's name completely

Tags: xcode, xcode10

[[image]]

It is like the picture shows. I can't get complete name of subclass.
Please help me fix it.

Comment: It appears that you're running Xcode on Mojave (which at this point is beta software), so I guess this could be a bug (seems like the labels are cut off). Have you tried to manually type your subclass name instead of choosing one?

Comment: yes,it is no problem to type subclass name,but it is troublesome without choosing one

Comment: I agree. The best thing you can do is to report the bug (_Help > Report an Issue_) so it gets fixed before Mojave gets released.